# Best approach to create CMS in Heroku platform

Tags: heroku

We have a requirement of creating a content management system in Heroku platform. I am from a Java background and as I am new to Heroku, I would like to know which approach or technology can be used to create the application in Heroku platform.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you